# When some partitions are crashed can we query on other partitions

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have a large table with about 40 partition.
Each partition belongs to different area data.
I found that some partition are crashed and i also want to work on other partitions at the same time keeping crashed partitions as it is.
So can i query on other partition, using PARTITION in SELECT statement, when some partitions are crashed?
I would appreciate if somebody helps me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can, in some sense, restrict select statements to certain partitions. There's no parameter that allow to select a partition (wouldn't make sense since partition access is controlled by the partitioning limits) but you can write your query so that it only retrieves data from specific partitions. For instance if you have partitioned by date you can use a WHERE clause that only addresses specific dates, working so only with specific partitions.